# GSAP, How to using TweenMax.to animate different properties in the selected element array?

Tags: animation, gsap

For instant.

```
TweenMax.to($('.letter'), 0.2, {
    x: x,
    y: y,
});
```

I wanna that

$('.letter:eq(0)') animate to the property{x:0.1, y:0.3}

$('.letter:eq(1)') animate to the property{x:0.2, y:0.4}

$('.letter:eq(2)') animate to the property{x:0.2, y:0.5}
....

If I have more than 20 elements with class 'letter', and the x & y property is random generated, How shall I achieve my goal with the best succinct way?

Comment: `stagger` methods with `cycle` property should help. see this: https://youtu.be/0HhjSPVuRHA?t=4m

Comment: @Tahir Ahmed thanks!